# Node.js - Using Multer to upload images in MongoDB and having trouble updating them

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, multer

I was able to successfully upload images in my MongoDB project using Multer, but I'm stuck on how to update them. When I tried using the same trick in my Edit function, the log says I can't set headers after they're sent to the client. For context, I'll put in my code for uploading and editing

```
router.get('/upload', IsLoggedIn, (req, res, next) => {
    res.render('mods/upload', {title: 'Upload a mod', user: req.user});
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, './mods/upload.hbs'));
});

router.post('/upload', upload.single('image'), IsLoggedIn, (req, res, next) => {
    console.log(req.file);
    Mod.create({
        name: req.body.name,
        image: req.file.filename,
        file: req.body.file
    }, (err, newMod) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
        else {
            res.redirect('/mods');
        }
    });
});
```

```
router.get('/edit/:_id', IsLoggedIn, (req, res, next) => {
        Mod.findById(req.params._id, (err, mod) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
            else {
                res.render('mods/edit', {
                    title: 'Edit mod',
                    mod: mod,
                    user: req.user
                })
            }
        }).sort({name: 1});
        res.render('mods/edit');
        res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, './mods/edit.hbs'));
    });

    router.post('/edit/:_id', upload.single('image'), IsLoggedIn, (req, res, next) => {
       Mod.findOneAndUpdate(
            {
                _id: req.params._id
            },
            {
                name: req.body.name,
                image: req.file.filename,
                file: req.body.file
            },
            (err, updatedProject) => {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                }
                else {
                    res.redirect('/mods');
                }
            }
        )
    });
```

Am I even able to update images in the same fashion, or is there something entirely different I should be doing? I'm still super new to Multer and I haven't done a whole lot with MongoDB, so any guidance would be super appreciated!

Comment: Responding with content is a one-time thing per request. You can't use `res.render()` multiple times or mix it with `res.sendFile()`

Comment: Could I be remembering something wrong then? Your comment makes sense, but my upload getter works by using both render and sendFile, and my problem is only apparent in my edit function. What is different about updating?